# postfix: milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from ...: 4.7.1 Service unavailable (opendkim)

Tags: postfix, opendkim

I configured OpenDkim to work with postfix and I'm getting the following error when I try to send mail out:

```
postfix/cleanup[11542]: 40F271A291A: milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from ***[***]: 4.7.1 Service unavailable - try again later; from=<me@example.com> to=<me2@hotmail.es> proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.1.10]>
```

I've configured opendkim to use a unix socket, and it's working:

```
[chazy@mail ~]$ sudo netstat -nalp | grep dkim
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     144135   11267/opendkim       /run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     147626   11267/opendkim       /run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    144137   11267/opendkim
```

Opendkim is started by it's own user, as suggested by the Arch wiki (as well as the other security recommendations). The folders are also owned by opendkim:mail.

I'm using the same selector and signing key for all domains, is that a problem?

The postfix configuration is as follows:

```
# DKIM
milter_default_action = accept
smtpd_milters = unix:/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters = unix:/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

No anti-spam service installed for the moment, just a basic postfix/dovecot/opendkim configuration to test the server.

Opendkim config:

```
# /etc/opendkim/opendkim.conf

BaseDirectory           /var/lib/opendkim
Canonicalization        relaxed/simple
Domain                  domain1.com domain2.com
ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts           refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
KeyFile                 /etc/opendkim/201704.private
KeyTable                refile:/etc/opendkim/KeyTable
Selector                201704
SigningTable            refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
Socket                  local:/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
Syslog                  Yes
TemporaryDirectory      /run/opendkim
UMask                   002
UserID                  opendkim:mail
```

TrustedHosts config:

```
# /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts

# Trusted Hosts List
127.0.0.1
::1
x.x.x.x # Server IP
mail.maindomain.com

# Domains
maindomain.com
domain2.com
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem, in my case, was that the signing key file had root owner, so doing:

```
sudo chown opendkim:mail /etc/opendkim/selector.private
```

Fixed the problem.

If this is not your problem, don't forget to take a look at the journal, for both! postfix and opendkim (i forgot to lookup opendkim and there it was the error):

```
journalctl --follow --unit postfix.service --unit opendkim.service
```

Answer (score 2):

### Problem:

There's yet another thingy that will cause this error which I just discovered to my great pain:

```
BaseDirectory          /run/opendkim
```

You'd think that you're pointing opendkim to where the PID lives...

### Solution:

```
#BaseDirectory          /run/opendkim
```

This is what the directive ***actually*** does and why the service was rendered "***milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from ...: 4.7.1 Service unavailable***"

> BaseDirectory (string)
>
> If set, instructs the filter to change to the specified directory
> using chdir(2) before doing anything else. This means any files
> referenced elsewhere in the configuration file can be specified
> relative to this directory. It’s also useful for arranging that any
> crash dumps will be saved to a specific location.

[REF: http://www.opendkim.org/opendkim.conf.5.html](http://www.opendkim.org/opendkim.conf.5.html)

As soon as I commented it out, everything started to work.

This was a default value I was using and saw other specimen configs using this value so initially didn't give it weight and pursued the solutions which related to incorrect permissions.

Ensure you have a correct value for this directive or you will spend hours chasing your tail. The logging isn't helpful to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

Try and see if removing the "*@" from your the file you use as your signing table works. This is what was causing it for me, even though I had

```
SigningTable      refile:<directory to signing table file>
```

in my opendkim.conf.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the outgoing message was simply too big.

After fixing the issue, I got:

```
Sep 24 20:05:20 va1my postfix/smtp[23682]: C553B48F30: to=<XXX>, relay=XXXXX:25, delay=2979299, delays=2979298/0.01/0.13/0.72, dsn=5.2.3, status=bounced (host XXXXXX said: 552-5.2.3 Your message exceeded message size limits. Please visit 552-5.2.3  XXXX  to view our size 552 5.2.3 guidelines.  (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

To fix it, I added to `/etc/opendkim.conf`:

```
MaximumHeaders 0
```

and restarted opendkim `service opendkim restart`  (or `systemctl restart opendkim`).

Setting a limit of 256k did not help, because the header was bigger, so I set 0 which disables the limit.  I could comment the line again as the root cause is gone.

### Sidenote, the real cause

The headers were likely too big because of having piped the output of a log to sendmail without adding a header.

I achieved that like this and did not realize this mail got stuck:

```
grep FILTER FILE | sendmail user@example.com
```

To properly script using "sendmail", I did something as below :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# TMP_FILE and SUBJECT are set somewhere in the script.

# Prepend the $SUBJECT to the script output sent by mail.

  ( echo "Subject: $SUBJECT" \
    && cat $TMP_FILE \
  ) | \
  /usr/sbin/sendmail $1
```